# Pandas read_csv alters the columns when it starts with 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have a script where I read from a csv file some zipcodes. 
The format of the zipcodes are like this:

```
zipcode
75180
90672
01037
20253
09117
31029
07745
90453
12105
18140
36108
10403
76470
06628
93105
88069
31094
84095
63069
```

Then I run a script:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time

file = '/Users/zipcode.csv'
reader = pd.read_csv(file, sep=';', encoding='utf-8-sig')

zipcodes = reader["zipcode"].astype(str)
base_url = "https://api.blabla/?zipcode={zipcode}"
headers = {'Authentication': 'random'}

for zipcode in zipcodes:
    url = base_url.format(zipcode=zipcode)
    r = requests.get(url,
                     headers=headers)
    for r_info in r.json()["data"]:
        print zipcode,r_info["id"]
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

However, whenever there is a zipcode starting with 0, the result I get is with 4 digits and it can't match with the actual 0. 
I have formatted my csv to have a text column in it, but still it doesn't work.

The zipcodes I get are like this:

```
zipcode
75180
90672
1037
20253
9117
31029
7745
90453
12105
18140
36108
10403
76470
6628
93105
88069
31094
84095
63069
```

Do you have any idea how can this be resolved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the `dtype` as `str`:

```
reader = pd.read_csv(file, sep=';', encoding='utf-8-sig', dtype=str)
```

to read those values as str:

```
In [152]:
import pandas as pd
import io
t="""zipcode
75180
90672
01037
20253
09117
31029
07745
90453
12105
18140
36108
10403
76470
06628
93105
88069
31094
84095
63069"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), dtype=str)
df

Out[152]:
   zipcode
0    75180
1    90672
2    01037
3    20253
4    09117
5    31029
6    07745
7    90453
8    12105
9    18140
10   36108
11   10403
12   76470
13   06628
14   93105
15   88069
16   31094
17   84095
18   63069
```

by default pandas sniffs the `dytpes` and in this case it thinks they are numeric so you lose leading zeroes

You can also do this as a post-processing step by casting to `str` and then using the vectorised [`str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html):

```
In [154]:
df['zipcode'] = df['zipcode'].astype(str).str.zfill(5)
df

Out[154]:
   zipcode
0    75180
1    90672
2    01037
3    20253
4    09117
5    31029
6    07745
7    90453
8    12105
9    18140
10   36108
11   10403
12   76470
13   06628
14   93105
15   88069
16   31094
17   84095
18   63069
```

Comment: YES!! Thanks so much :D