# Losing data structure with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

When I loading data from a CSV file with Pandas The numerical column changes in another word the comuln gets converted to number type for exemple "074050" becoming 74050 and that first 0 is very important 
How i can keep the data as it is in the file?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40244186/pandas-read-csv-alters-the-columns-when-it-starts-with-0

Comment: use `dtype=str` parameter on `pd.read_csv()`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', converters={'column_name': str})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig', dtype=str)
```

Comment: That works, thank you